# Expo Build failed : Android build failed: Gradle build failed for run gradlew - react native base application

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, native-base

While build my expo managed workflow react native base project on expo using the command `eas build -p android`. the app build was failed on run gradlew

twhile go through the logs, its says app is currently compiled against android-33 but expecting android-34

```
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction


   > An issue was found when checking AAR metadata:


       1.  Dependency 'androidx.browser:browser:1.6.0-beta01' requires libraries and applications that
depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the Android APIs.

          :app is currently compiled against android-33.

           Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle

           plugin 7.4.1 is 33.

           Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle

           plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use

           compileSdkVerion of at least 34.
```

while search for solutions, i found that changing complieSdkversion and TargetedSdkVersion to 34 in app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
......
 "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.kannan.mobileapp",
      "compileSdkVersion": 34,
      "targetSdkVersion":34
    },
}}
```

but this wasn't worked out for me.

In my root project directory i don't have any android folder and `build.gradle` file so I can't do any changes in it. because the project was under expo managed workflow.

is there any possible solutions for changing the complied sdk version to `android-34`?

Comment: Seems like some of the library you're using is trying to use `androidx.browser:browser:1.6.0-beta01` dependency which targets 34 sdk. Can you provide more details like dependencies list by  and removing the target version 34  & running `npm list` or  you can simply try to install dependencies with `expo install`

Comment: This was my `npm list` 
@babel/core@7.22.9,@react-native-async-storage/async-storage@1.17.11,@react-native-community/netinfo@9.3.7,@react-navigation/bottom-tabs@6.5.8,@react-navigation/native-stack@6.9.13,@react-navigation/native@6.1.7,@react-navigation/stack@6.3.17,@types/react-native-maps@0.24.2,@types/react-native@0.67.21,@types/react@18.0.38,amazon-cognito-identity-js@5.2.14,aws-amplify@4.3.46,expo-device@5.2.1,expo-image-picker@14.3.2,expo-location@15.1.1,expo-notifications@0.18.1,expo-status-bar@1.4.4,expo-updates@0.16.4,expo@48.0.20,native-base@3.4.28,react-dom@18.2.0

Comment: continued - react-hook-form@7.45.2,react-native-easy-grid@0.2.2,react-native-image-picker@5.6.0,react-native-inappbrowser-reborn@3.7.0,react-native-maps@1.3.2,react-native-pager-view@6.1.2,react-native-root-toast@3.4.1,react-native-safe-area-context@4.5.0,react-native-screens@3.20.0,react-native-svg@13.4.0,react-native-tab-view@3.5.2,react-native-web@0.18.12,react-native-webview@11.26.0,react-native@0.71.12,react@18.2.0,typescript@4.9.5

Answer (score 0):

I solved it on my own, i found out the solution in github. https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/23488